# How to add more parameter in kannel sendsms?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel, smpp

I want to add more parameter in sendsms HTTP URL only for create kannel-access.log and kannel.log.

example

```
http://<IP>:port/cgi-bin/sendsms?to=1234567890&from=Test&user=foo&password=bar&text=Test+msg
&param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

Here param1, param2 and param3 are extra http parameters and i wnat to add in logging as well. 
example of kannel-access.log :

```
2012-12-12 14:08:01 Sent SMS [SMSC:SMSC1] 
[SVC:SMSC1] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:1812121214063308550] 
[META:] [from:ABC] [to:1234567890] [flags:-1:0:-1:-1:7] 
[msg:107:Test+sms] [udh:0:]
[param1=param1][param2=param2][param3=param3]
```

Please help me to make changes in sendms command and logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binfo or/and account parameters, its values will be logged in your access-log and then you can do whatever you want with that log file.

From kannel's user guide:

- **account**:
  Optional. Account name or number to carry forward for billing purposes. This field is logged as ACT in the log file so it allows you to do some accounting on it if your front end uses the same username for all services but wants to distinguish them in the log. In the case of a HTTP SMSC type the account name is prepended with the service-name (username) and a colon (:) and forwarded to the next instance of Kannel. This allows hierarchical accounting.
- **binfo**:
  Optional. Billing identifier/information proxy field used to pass arbitrary billing transaction IDs or information to the specific SMSC modules. For EMI2 this is encapsulated into the XSer 0c field, for SMPP this is encapsulated into the service_type of the submit_sm PDU.